# Clicking A Button In A CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I'm adding a button to a collection view cell's custom class, but having trouble getting it to click.

Here's how I declare the button in the cell custom class:

```
let shareBtn: UIButton = {
    let roundBtn = UIButton()
    roundBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
    roundBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    roundBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    roundBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    roundBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share"), for: .normal)
    roundBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    roundBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    roundBtn.isEnabled = true

    return roundBtn
}()
```

Here is the method the selector calls:

```
func shareAction(button: UIButton){
    print("shareAction")
}
```

Here how I add the button in the init

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    contentView.addSubview(shareBtn)

    shareBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    shareBtn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -100).isActive = true
    shareBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    shareBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    shareBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
```

I tried adding the button to both - the contentView and the self but both give the same result, which is unclickable button.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the way you're creating the button whenever you access `shareBtn`, you're always creating a new instance because it's a computed variable. That's why when you write this:

```
addSubview(shareBtn)
 shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

the button you add as a subview and the button you add the target to are different instances. You must use a `lazy var` for the `shareBtn` like the following:

```
lazy var shareBtn: UIButton = {
    let roundBtn = UIButton()
    roundBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
    roundBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    roundBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    roundBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    roundBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "share"), for: .normal)
    roundBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    roundBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    roundBtn.isEnabled = true

    return roundBtn
}()
```

This way only one instance will be created and assigned to `shareBtn` when you access it the first time and all subsequent accesses will use the same instance.

Comment: what? man you're right. why would swift do that it is the same constant why create new instance of it, I don't understand. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The button was under a page control view that was added in the parent view controller. Also I needed to call the action method after adding the subview to the cell:

```
 addSubview(shareBtn)
 shareBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareAction(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```